# Touchpad stop working

Tags: 11.10, touchpad, hp

I have an HP 430 PC-Notebook using Oneiric. And sometimes my touchpad just stops working.(I haven't installed anything, just **safe** playing with terminal following [linuxcommand.org](http://linuxcommand.org)

In Windows, I could two-finger touch to toggle locking the touchpad.

And as far as I know, Ubuntu doesn't have this function so I don't think that's the problem...

Comment: By "hole", I think you are referring to the little toggle button on the upper left to turn it on and off.

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be a bug. I'm running ubuntu release 11.10 and this problem occurred regulary. I solved this issue by un-checking the setting to disable the touchpad while typing in the Mouse and Touchpad setting application.

Regards

Answer (score -1):

this is a common problem, there are several options
Options

1.look up the mouse options in System settings

1. Install `dconf-tools`

   - Launch it
   - Search for: `org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.touchpad`
   - Check `touchpad-enable`
2. See here is a known bug and there on the responses of people there are different solutions, https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+bug/80410

4.happens to me when I close session and open again, the touchpad works.

good luck

Comment: Please format your post using proper code and line breaks as it is *very* difficult to read otherwise.

Comment: I don't have 'touchpad' in 'plugins'.